# How to change condition from a while loop

Tags: python

I am trying to create a reading list, using 2 functions - one to add books and another to display books. The add books function need to execute till such time user confirms that the update is completed. Following is the code :

```
book_list = []

def add_books(books):
    book_record = {}
    completed = "no"
    while completed == "no":
        title = input("Enter title : ")
        author = input("Enter author : ")
        year = input("Enter year of publication : ")
        book_record.update({"title": title, "author": author, "year_publ": year})
        books.append(book_record)
        print(books)
        completed = input("update completed ? yes/no")
    return books


def display_books(books):
    for book in books:
        title = book["title"]
        author = book["author"]
        year = book["year_publ"]
        print(f"{title}, {author}, {year}")


option = input("Enter 'a' to add and 'd' to display the books or 'q' to quit :")

while option != "q" :
    if option == "a":
        book_list = add_books(book_list)
    elif option == "d":
        display_books(book_list)
    else:
        print("Invalid Option")
        option = input("Enter 'a' to add and 'd' to display the books or 'q' to quit :")
```

When I execute this code, the While loop ignores the completed condition and keeps asking for adding more books even though the user confirms updated completed.

What is wrong ? I understand that I am trying to update completed inside the loop, and that may be the reason. What are the options ?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks and Regards

Sachin

Comment: _When I execute this code, the While loop ignores the completed condition and keeps asking for adding more books even though the user confirms updated completed._ That loops seems fine to me, have you done any debugging?

Comment: Don't forget to vote on the answers that helped you and pick one of them as accepted answer when your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is with the `option = input("Enter 'a' to add and 'd' to display the books or 'q' to quit :")`. You are asking only one time for the option, what you need is an endless loop to continue asking for the new option. On your approach when the "user" chooses the "a" option he/she never gets asked again so the options still remains on "a" thus the `add_books()` function running endless!

You should change the last part to:

```py
while True:
    option = input("Enter 'a' to add and 'd' to display the books or 'q' to quit :")

    if option == "a":
        book_list = add_books(book_list)
    elif option == "d":
        display_books(book_list)
    elif option == "q":
        quit()
    else:
        print("Invalid Option")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code keeps asking because `option` still is `"a"` after `add_books` has finished, and your "main" loop does not get a new value for `option` from the user.

Always make the *"Do you want to continue?"* question part of the loop.

I would recommend to use endless loops (`while True:`) with a conditional `break` for these kinds of tasks. It's easier to follow (in my opinion):

Like this - I've added a helper function `input_letter` that returns the trimmed, lower-case first letter of the user's response, for easier management later):

```
book_list = []

def input_letter(prompt):
    return input(prompt).strip().lower()[0::1]

def add_books(books):
    while True:
        title = input("Enter title: ")
        author = input("Enter author: ")
        year = input("Enter year of publication: ")
        books.append({"title": title, "author": author, "year_publ": year})
        if input_letter("More? (y)es / (n)o ") == "y":
            break

    return books

def display_books(books):
    for book in books:
        title = book["title"]
        author = book["author"]
        year = book["year_publ"]
        print(f"{title}, {author}, {year}")

while True:
    option = input_letter("(a)dd book, (d)isplay books, (q)uit: ")
    if option == "a":
        add_books(book_list)
    elif option == "d":
        display_books(book_list)
    elif option == "q":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?:

```
def add_books(books):
book_record = {}
completed = "no"
while True:
    title = input("Enter title : ")
    author = input("Enter author : ")
    year = input("Enter year of publication : ")
    book_record.update({"title": title, "author": author, "year_publ": year})
    books.append(book_record)
    print(books)
    completed = input("update completed ? yes/no")
    if completed == 'yes':
        break
return books
```

Answer (score 0):

if you whant to keep ypur code use:
another condintion to tell the loop that the completed have been updated and quit it!

```
book_list = []

def add_books(books):
    book_record = {}
    completed = "no"
    while completed == "no":
        title = input("Enter title : ")
        author = input("Enter author : ")
        year = input("Enter year of publication : ")
        book_record.update({"title": title, "author": author, "year_publ": year})
        books.append(book_record)
        print(books)
        completed = input("update completed ? yes/no")

        if completed == "yes":
            completed = completed
            break
    return books


def display_books(books):
    for book in books:
        title = book["title"]
        author = book["author"]
        year = book["year_publ"]
        print(f"{title}, {author}, {year}")


option = input("Enter 'a' to add and 'd' to display the books or 'q' to quit :")

while option != "q" :
    if option == "a":
        book_list = add_books(book_list)
    elif option == "d":
        display_books(book_list)
    else:
        print("Invalid Option")
    option = input("Enter 'a' to add and 'd' to display the books or 'q' to quit :")
```